# Sum a range of column

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

I am kind of new to excel, could you please help me with below question?

I want to a sum of column only if the all the column in the row have value, could you please help me on this?

```
   A B C D E F

 1 1 2 3 4 5 10

 2 6 4 5 6 7 9

 3 8   5 6 7 10

 4 9    3 3  3
```

I want to do a sum of f1:f100 and I want to do sum only if A B C D E have values in it, if any of the column in a row have empty value, i want to ignore it. like now I need to ignore F3 and F4.

Basil Abraham.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUMIFS like this

`=SUMIFS(F1:F100,A1:A100,"<>",B1:B100,"<>",C1:C100,"<>",D1:D100,"<>",E1:E100,"<>")`

or this version is less transparent but more easily "extensible" if you want to check more than 5 columns

`=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTBLANK(OFFSET(A1:E1,ROW(A1:A100)-ROW(A1),0))=0)+0,F1:F100)`

Comment: The second option is not working for it is showing mismatched range length, I am not sure what is the issue. May be need to see further

Comment: Both formulas work OK for me - I can attach a sample if you want. Did the first one work as you wanted? If you amended the second one for different ranges then can you post the revised version?

Answer (score 0):

select the rows that you want to sum and use the S button, empty rows do not care you.

Comment: I want to have this as kind of formula so do not do it manually every time.